# Concurrency Limit across endpoints in MassTransit (C#)

Tags: c#, concurrency, rabbitmq, masstransit

Mass Transit 3.5,
RabbitMq

I have a bus connected service that listens on number of queues.

- Q1
- Q2
- Q3
- Q4
  etc

All queues are accepting same message type, and all of them are using a competing consumer pattern, where there are multiple services on different machines listening on these same queues.

What I am after is setting a concurrency limit on all these queues together, per single process.

I have a limited resource (number of available licenses), and need to limit concurrent requests to number of available licenses per machine.

So machine A may have 4, machine B may have 10, etc.

I do not want machine A to consume any message from all these queues if I already have 4 consumers processing messages across all queues, it should let others (machine B, C, etc) to consume it if they have available resources.

My issue is that using

```
    sbc.UseConcurrencyLimit(4)
```

inside

```
    var bus = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq
```

is setting concurrency limit per queue, so if I have 4 of them, they are all added up.

What I need is for all of the queues to cumulatively work up to that concurrency limit, but not exceed it.

Is there a built-in way in MassTransit to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to limit concurrency across multiple services. That would require using some type of global resource manager, and it just isn't something that MassTransit supports out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing this answer for the latest version of MassTransit, which is currently Version 8. In Version 8, you have the ability to limit concurrency in two different contexts.

First, when defining a ReceiveEndpoint, you can set the maximum concurrency for each specific queue. Here's an example:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("Q_Import_1", e =>
{
    e.ConfigureConsumer<TrafficImportConsumer>(context);
    e.UseConcurrencyLimit(1);
});

cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("Q_Import_2", e =>
{
    e.ConfigureConsumer<TrafficImportConsumer>(context);
    e.UseConcurrencyLimit(1);
});
```

Secondly, when adding the MassTransit service to your application, you can set the UseConcurrencyLimit option there to define the maximum cumulative concurrency for the entire application. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x => 
x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
{
    cfg.UseConcurrencyLimit(2);
    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
}));
```

In this example, each queue will have a maximum concurrency of 1, but the entire application will not exceed a total of two concurrent tasks.